# bug database at Joel Test, What is the appropriate definition?

Tags: testing

bug database means store a list of database regarding bugs. How to utilize?

- What is the appropriate definition of `bug database` at Joel Test?

Comment: Please mention the reason why you guys placing down vote. It will help me to improve my question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug database is a central database used to store bugs and preferably all contacts gegarding the bug.

It can be as simple as a spreadsheet, if that suits the need of the company. But there are great tools available to manage the bugs and their resolution.

Bugs are reported by a reporter (either the Q&A department or a user). They are planned for a release and assigned to a developer. The developer tries to solve the bugs in order of priority (and or severity). And it is possible to have a dialogue with the reporter (either through the bug tool or email).

Some bug tools have graphs to monitor the schedule (planned versus resolved) and gives management a tool to change scope or release date.

Answer (score 0):

Joel is talking about some kind of system to track bugs discovered by testers or users.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_tracking_system

Whether a company chooses to prioritise fixing bugs or developing new features says a lot about their priorities and outlook.

There are lots of tools to help you keep track of bugs.  Joel himself makes a good one - [www.fogbugz.com](http://www.fogbugz.com)